# pcl (pointcloud) to mesh

Tags: mesh, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to convert pointcloud data set to mesh. What I know is that first I need to convert pointcloud recorded in a rosbag to pcd, then pcd to ply, and finally ply to mesh using MeshLab.

I can create number of pcd files from pointcloud using

```
rosrun pcl_ros bag_to_pcd <input_file.bag> <topic> <output_directory>
```

but I have no idea how to convert pcd files to a ply file. Can anyone suggest me how to do pcd to ply or if there is a better way to convert pcl to mesh?

Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222100/pcl-(pointcloud)-to-mesh/) by [AsifA](https://answers.ros.org/users/3497/asifa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2015-12-07

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest using the [pcl_converter](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/tools/converter.cpp) tool that I have committed recently, it allows to convert between multiple formats easily:

```
Available formats types for SOURCE and DEST:
           OBJ (Wavefront)
           PCD (Point Cloud Library)
           PLY (Polygon File Format)
           STL (STereoLithography)
           VTK (The Visualization Toolkit)
```

As for the creation of a mesh starting from a point cloud, this is not a conversion but rather a creation.
The process of connecting points of a point cloud by faces is called triangulation, mesh reconstruction, meshing.

You will find more information in the PCL tutorials, [greedy triangulation](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/greedy_projection.php#greedy-triangulation) is a good start.

---

Originally posted by [VictorLamoine](https://answers.ros.org/users/20682/victorlamoine/) with karma: 1505 on 2016-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0